# Errors when accessing site from Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jcarousel, jquery-dotdotdot

[image]

When I access this site from Internet Explorer 11 I got these three errors. If I use other browser everything is going ok, what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According the screenshot and the description, it seems that you are using the Dotdotdot plugin and jcarousel plugin.

First, try to use F12 developer tools to check whether the related plugin reference is load success. If not, please check the JQuery reference path.

Second, from the [dotdotdot plugin document](https://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/), we can find that:

*The dotdotdot javascript plugin targets modern browsers that support ES5, meaning Internet Explorer 10 and earlier are not supported. For Internet Explorer 11, you''ll need [some polyfills](https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default%2CElement.prototype.append%2CElement.prototype.prepend%2CElement.prototype.remove%2CElement.prototype.replaceWith%2CElement.prototype.classList%2CElement.prototype.cloneNode%2CElement.prototype.matches). If you need support for Internet Explorer 9 or 10, use the legacy (jQuery) version: [version 3.2.3](https://github.com/FrDH/dotdotdot-JS/releases/tag/v3.2.3).*

And, I have checked the Jcarousel plugin sample, they all work well with IE 11 browser. But from the [Jcarousel forum](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/832), I found that the issue might be related to the JQuery version.

So, you could also try to change the JQuery version to [3.0.0 version](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js), See all versions of jQuery from [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/3.2.0).

For the IsMobile is Undefined error, whether you are using some jquery plugin? Check your code where you defined this article.

If the suggestions above don't work, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).